# Unable to position button in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a problem I just can't seem to solve despite following directions in my previous post, I just began learning html/css. This is my button as it appears right now:
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzIJm.png)

& this is where I would like it to appear. It does not seem to move despite changing the top, left or bottom:

[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TL3t2.png)

& this is where I want it to be. The background is simply an image its not multiple divs. this is the only code I have:

```
<section>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="container">
      
      <div class="wrap">
        <div class="fix-7-12">
         <div><p class="ae-2">
            <button style{
              top: 100px;
              right: 1000px;
              left: 10000000px;
            }
              >Try yourself</button
            >
          </p></div>>
          
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <img
    src="assets/img/background/fire2.png"
    width="1450"
    height="850"
  ></img>
</section>
```

Comment: I'd encourage you to read up on positioning in CSS. [CSS-Tricks has a good overview](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/position/).

It can also be helpful when experimenting with code to use [codepen](https://codepen.io/pen/) as it gives immediate feedback.

Comment: why your ```left``` position is too big?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use left, top etc. styles with percentages. If we look at the center of the button in the second picture:

top: 35%, left: 60%

Also, you should change display to block in order to see the button as a rectangle element. I gave also width and height. You can change them if you want.

So, I changed your HTML code as:

```html
<section>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="wrap">
                <div class="fix-7-12">
                    <div><p class="ae-2">
                        <button 
                            style="position: absolute; display: block; top: 35%; left: 60%;
                                width: 120px; height: 60px;">
                            Try yourself
                        </button>
                    </p></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <img
        src="assets/img/background/fire2.png"
        width="1450"
        height="850"
    >
</section>
```

These are the screenshots:

[image][image]

Comment: Maybe, you can increase the top value a bit like to 40%. Hope, I helped you.

Comment: Is it possible to change the position by changing the percentages? I change them but the button doesn't move :(

Comment: You can change top and left values. You can see the result more clear by pressing "Full page" text in the bottom of the code snippet.

Comment: I added screenshots to my answer. As you see, the position of the button changes if you change the left and top values.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few mistakes in your HTML. Firstly, the `style` attribute needs to be a string. The `position` attribute needs to be first. So it would be `"position: absolute;top: 100px;right: 1000px; left: 10000000px;"`. `img` tags do not have a closing tag.

Correct HTML:

```html
<section>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="container">
      
      <div class="wrap">
        <div class="fix-7-12">
         <div><p class="ae-2">
            <button style="position: absolute;top: 100px;right: 1000px; left: 10000000px;"
              >Try yourself</button
            >
          </p></div>>
          
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <img
    src="assets/img/background/fire2.png"
    width="1450"
    height="850"
  >
</section>
```

Comment: There seems to be a bug here, it opens up my image but says 'this is the accepted answer for this question" in the middle instead of having a button